# NSLayoutConstraint and dynamic UITableViewCell height

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

How to write (or do in IB) layout constraints for dynamic tableViewCell height? For example if there is textView (sized to fit) in contenView of cell and I want to cell to be as high as label.

Answer (score 3):

If you have set up your constraints fully and correctly, you can calculate the height by getting an instance of the cell and calling `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize` on it. This will cause your instance to contract around the constraints, thus giving you the desired height.

However, the cells in the table will still get their height from `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`. So you must still do what you would have done before auto layout existed: you must calculate the heights for all the cells in advance so that you can respond to a barrage of `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` calls. The difference is that now you are using auto layout to perform the height calculation instead of whatever you were doing before.

Now for the bad news: for a long table, this can be slow.